# Resource gets force regenerated if conut attribute is specified

Tags: terraform

Terraform force regenerated this resource even if nothing has changed.

Terraform version: terraform_0.15.3_linux_amd64

I have seen this problem only if `count` attribute is specified.

```
resource "aws_instance" "apache_ec2" {
  count = var.instance_count
  // -- Truncated --
  instance_type   = var.apache_ec2-instance_type
  ami             = var.ami  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide tf `plan` output to show what exactly changes according to tf?

Comment: plan screenshot pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:
There were security groups rules getting regenerated and causing recreate of the EC2 resource.

Fix:
In the `aws_instance` I had to change `security_groups` to`vpc_security_group_ids` and that stopped recreation of EC2 in response to recreate of security group rules.